# PHP Warning: stristr(): Empty needle in line

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I get a strange behavior from the following code ..it's intended to give auto-complete options for the user on every key-press

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function autoComplete(str) {
    debugger;
    if (str) {
        $.ajax({
            type:'GET' ,
            url:"index.php?q=" + str ,
            success:function(response){
                $("#autoComplete").html(response) ;
            }
        })
    }
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#text").keypress(function() {
        autoComplete($("#text").val())
    });
})
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="index.php"  >
<input type="text" id="text"  />
<div id="autoComplete"></div>

</form>

<?php

if (isset($_GET["q"]))
{
  $a[] = "Android";
   $a[] = "B programming language";
   $a[] = "C programming language";
   $a[] = "D programming language";
   $a[] = "euphoria";
   $a[] = "F#";
   $a[] = "GWT";
   $a[] = "HTML5";
   $a[] = "ibatis";
   $a[] = "Java";
   $a[] = "K programming language";
   $a[] = "Lisp";
   $a[] = "Microsoft technologies";
   $a[] = "Networking";
   $a[] = "Open Source";
   $a[] = "Prototype";
   $a[] = "QC";
   $a[] = "Restful web services";
   $a[] = "Scrum";
   $a[] = "Testing";
   $a[] = "UML";
   $a[] = "VB Script";
   $a[] = "Web Technologies";
   $a[] = "Xerox Technology";
   $a[] = "YQL";
   $a[] = "ZOPL";
   $ACText = $_GET["q"] ; 
   $ACBox = "";

  foreach($a as $name)
  {
    if($name){
    if (stristr($ACText , substr("$name" , 0 , strlen($ACText))))
    {
        $ACText = $name ; 
        $ACBox .="<p>$ACText</p>" ; 
        $ACText = "" ; 
    }
  }
  }
  if($ACBox)
  {
    echo $ACBox  ; 
  }
    }

?>
</body>
</html>
```

when entering text in the input element the form unexpectedly creates another input element under the existed one and display multiple warning messages ... I tried to hide those warning messages using error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE); .. but the browser got very slow after I did that .... also I wanna know why another input element is displayed 
[image]

some help ?
(the auto-complete options were shown successfully)

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);` is not hiding the errors, it's showing more details/errors. You may want to use `error_reporting(false);`

Comment: @Tushar `$name` is defined in `foreach($a as $name)`

Comment: it's just a temporary variable for the foreach statement like (for every var name in the array a )

Comment: So, are we looking at index.php here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem might be here:

```
  foreach($a as $name)
  {
    if($name){
    if (stristr($ACText , substr("$name" , 0 , strlen($ACText))))
    {
        $ACText = $name ; 
        $ACBox .="<p>$ACText</p>" ; 
        $ACText = "" ; 
    }
  }
  }
```

After the first iteration of the loop, you set `$ACText` to a blank string. Next time the loop runs, `substr("$name", 0, 0)` is going to return an empty string. It's the needle to `stristr` and, like the error message says, is empty.

Comment: darn , you're right .. what a silly mistake -_- ...it's still creates input element though .. any idea why that is ?

Comment: @ProHaitham Because you tell the page to load itself via AJAX and the page has an input field on it. You set the HTML of the autocomplete div to be the same as the current page.

Comment: oh I thought `echo` outputs the response ... how to make the response the desired html/text then .. sorry for too many questions

Comment: @ProHaitham Either put your PHP in a different file or don't output any HTML when `isset($_GET["q"])`.

Comment: I got it .. I'll just need to put the php script inside the div and `echo` the html ... thanks a lot